# Comment rendre "naysayers" ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Quel mot/expression peut-on utiliser pour rendre en français le sens de "naysayers" comme décrit ci-dessous : https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=naysayer

> One who frequently engages in excessive complaining, negative banter
>   and/or a genuinely poor and downbeat attitude. Naysayers are
>   distinguished by their tendency to consistently view the glass half
>   empty, make frequent one-way trips to negative town, and constantly
>   emphasize the worst of a situation. They have the capacity to rant and
>   whine for hours on end about the most insignificant inconveniences.
>   They tend to travel solo, but have the keen ability to spread their
>   pessimistic attitude to a group of unsuspecting bystanders and
>   encourage others to employ their mindset.  Naysayers tend to blend in
>   with those around them rather well, granted they have learned over the
>   years to adapt to their surroundings. However, when the opportunity
>   arises, their true nature will be exposed and they will stop at
>   nothing to exclude others or bring a general sense of negativity to
>   any situation.  Not to be confused with non-naysayers who fight
>   against the negativity brought forth by naysayers, make the best of a
>   situation and are not afraid to call out a naysayer on the spot.

Comment: Not sure if this can officially be found in a dictionary entry, but I use "*un(e) défaitiste blasé(e)*" from time to time to describe such a person. {especially in light of the description in your 2nd sentence starting with "quelqu'un qui ne voit le verre qu'à moitié vide"}

Comment: Let me try something: *a typical Frenchman*? ;-)

Comment: Another suggestion: ***un gilet jaune***...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pour reprendre la connotation négative du terme et les aspects de complainte de *naysayer*, je proposerais **geignard** ou **pleurnicheur** qui correspond bien aux aspects suivants :

> constantly emphasize the worst of a situation
>
> frequently engages in excessive complaining
>
> They have the capacity to rant and whine for hours on end about the most insignificant inconveniences.

Dans un sens un peu moins fort, plus fréquent en journalisme, on peut aussi parler de **rabat-joie**. Exemple

> The naysayers argue that the rebound in consumer spending was expected.
>
> Les rabat-joies défendent que le rebond dans les dépenses des consommateurs était attendu.

Answer (score 6):

Bien que "pessimiste" soit effectivement une excellente traduction, je proposerais également **pisse-froid** qui s'adapte bien à la fois au sens et au registre de langue, et pourrait présenter une bonne alternative dans certains contextes.

Je trouve la définition du CNRTL un peu courte, mais [citons-la](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pisse-froid).

(Dans un registre légèrement plus soutenu mais avec un sens similaire, on aurait **esprit chagrin**, voire **triste sire**.)

Comment: et aussi son voisin, le [pisse-vinaigre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pisse-vinaigre)

Comment: D'après le TLFi, **pisse-froid** est « familier » ; et **naysayer** n'est pas ça, donc je ne comprends pas pourquoi vous dites que celui-là s'adapte bien au registre de langue de celui-ci. N'êtes-vous pas d'accord avec le TLFi ?

Comment: @jiliagre Oui, je l'avais oublié ! Excellent ajout.

Comment: @ruakh I would tend to agree, but these things aren't binary, rather questions of degree. I guess **pisse-froid** used to be familiar, but nowadays it certainly sounds more litterate or sophisticated, due to rarity. Zero chance to hear that at a bus stop in a lower/middle class suburb.

Answer (score 3):

Une personne **[pessimiste](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pessimiste)** semble correspondre à cette description.

**Définition:**

> Le pessimisme *(du mot latin pessimus superlatif de malus signifiant « mauvais »)* désigne un état d'esprit dans lequel un individu perçoit **négativement** la vie. Il s'agit d'une attitude mentale qui consiste à penser qu'un résultat indésirable et négatif peut être anticipé pour toute situation donnée. Les personnes pessimistes ont donc tendance à se concentrer sur les aspects **négatifs** de la vie en général.

**Exemple:**

> Certaines enquêtes ne retiennent que les études qui leur paraissent de bonne qualité ; d’autres sont moins exigeantes et il est
>   probable que les précautionnistes ou les écologistes ont tendance à
>   privilégier les travaux les plus **pessimistes**, au nom de l’heuristique
>   de la peur, […]. — (Maurice Tubiana, La Science au cœur de nos vies,
>   Odile Jacob, 2010, p.280)

- Une personne pessimiste perçoit donc le verre à moitié vide comme le
  [décrit](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=naysayer) le sens de "naysayers":

> Naysayers are distinguished by their tendency to consistently view the
>   glass half empty, make frequent one-way trips to **negative** town, and
>   constantly emphasize the worst of a situation.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other suggestions, you could use the word *râleur* and even stress that their "quality" of *râleurs* is a well-known habit with the familiar phrase *de service*.

> La mairie a agrandi la zone piétonnière, et je suis sûr que les *râleurs de service* se plaindront que cela a réduit le nombre de places de parking.

Comment: Oui, je trouve que c'est très proche aussi, j'avais pensé à "*les grincheux*", mais *râleurs* est probablement meilleur.